# I can't try to select columns from dataframe by using a list that contains the columns' names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to select specific columns to Dataframe by columns' names. I use a list to specify the names of the columns that I would select. But it keeps returning this error.

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['(',')', ' (',')', ' (',')',\n       ' (r,')', ' (',')', ' ')',\n       ' (',')', ' ('')', ' ('')',\n       ' ('')', ' (',')',\n       ' (',')', ' (' ')',\n       ' (',')', ' ('')',\n       ' ('')', ' (',')'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

I use the code below to do this operation:

```
def SelectColumn(df,liste):


  return pd.concat([df[e] for e in liste], axis=1)
```

The shape of the DataFrame is a little mess but the part that matters is the name of columns moreover.

So, once I import the csv file, I transformed the ligne that begin by  *#Leftover* to the column names of my dataframe and in the same time, I remove the current header, this is the function that make this operation :

```
def CreateHeader(df,name_of_line): 

#Select the wanted row for header in Dataframe 
  new_header = df.loc[df['#================================================================================'] == name_of_line]
  new_header_transposée = new_header.T                                     
  df = df[1:]
  df.columns = new_header_transposée


return df
```

Could someone help to fix it please ?

Comment: There appears to be indentation missing in the posted code: after the line with the `def` keyword. In addition, `list` is the name of a builtin type in Python, and indexing by it is probably not what is intended. Also, what value is passed in for `df` upon calling the function?

Comment: These column names don't make any sense. It suggests that something went wrong earlier on, when the DataFrame was created.

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis The value that passed in for df is the dataframe that I showed above.

Comment: The question is editable, which enables editing the question to add this information, and to adjust the code's indentation.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel what do you mean about "make any sense" ? I didn't create that DataFrame. It juste a Csv file that has been converted to df with the function pd.read_csv

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis Oh yes, my bad, I don't even see that I have wrongly copy the function on my question,  but I think the issue doesn't come from the identation because in my code, it's right, there is indentation

Comment: There was one level of indentation in the source of the question (Markdown) for the function's body, but that one level signified that those lines were part of the code block, because the code block was described using indentation in Markdown. An additional level of indentation was needed to create indentation after re rendering the code block as HTML output. In any case, I edited the question to amend this, and changed the Markdown of the code block to be a [fenced code block](https://github.github.com/gfm/#fenced-code-blocks), which does not need indentation to signify its lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the error

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['('#AFDX_OUTPUT_VL,')', ' ('Network Id,')', ' ('Connector name,')',\n       ' ('VL Identifier,')', ' ('VL name,')', ' ('Network Select,')',\n       ' ('BAG,')', ' ('Max frame size,')', ' ('Number of sub VL,')',\n       ' ('Sub VL Identifier,')', ' ('port characteristic,')',\n       ' ('IP frag allowed,')', ' ('Src IP address,')',\n       ' ('Dest IP address,')', ' ('Src UDP address,')',\n       ' ('Dest UDP address,')', ' ('Buffer Size,')'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

There are whitespaces in your column names, remove them by

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
# or
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

Also, there is a typo in your function

```py
def SelectColumn(df,liste):

    print(liste)
    df = df.loc[:,list]
                   ^
                   |
                   should be liste
    return df
```